# How do you change a piano staff to a treble staff in musescore?

Tags: musescore

For some reason a track on a midi file is being imported as a piano staff. It's a tenor voice part. How do I change the staff to show just the treble clef and remove the bass clef?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Edit|Instruments... menu item. It opens a window that allows you to add/remove instruments and staves. In this case, you would highlight the bass stave and click on the Remove button.

Answer (score 1):

Another technique is to add the "instrument" you DO want to the score, copy/paste the notes into it, then discard the original staves.  That way you automatically get the right playback sound set up for you.